# what are the differences between "be being done" and " be done?"

Tags: tenses

I heard from a listening material:
A person said:"And the subtitles probably only give the gist of what's actually being said.."
At the moment, I was thinking like, why did the speaker use "be being said", rather than "be said"?
Could anyone help me distinguish the differences between"be being said" and " be said"?

Comment: ...actually being said.... is the passive voice of 'be saying'. It is like, He is saying it = It is being said...Be said is like , says -> be said. She says it - it is said (by her).

Comment: The dialogue is going on while the subtitles are being shown, so the continuous tense is used.